# "Domain\computername$" instead of "nt authority\network service"

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

In the application pool within IIS, I have changed the `identity` (in advanced settings) of the `application pool` which is hosting web services to "`NetworkService`". I expected my web service to now run with identity "nt authority\network service" but instead it runs with identity Domain\computername$.

I would highly appreciate help on any system or IIS configuration parameters that I might have overlooked or missed.

- IIS 7.5
- Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Comment: This is by design.  The network service (and local system) accounts both use the identity of the computer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Thanks for your response. However, in on an old machine with IIS 6, I would get “nt authority\network service” as the identity.

Comment: That would have been on an older version of Windows, wouldn't it?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yes that was windows server 2003

Comment: Yep.  [The behaviour changed in Windows Vista.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I thank you for this information. The problem I'm facing is to bring the following 2 ends together - one is this GetUserName where you clarified. And the other is that WCF's `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity` is still running with "nt authority/network service".

Comment: You probably need to rearchitecture, e.g., change the way you retrieve the username.  Someone with more expertise in ASP.NET and WCF may be able to make a more specific suggestion, though it might help if you could edit the question to provide more detail as to why this is causing a problem.